# how to use vectorized H3 functions from h3-py?

Tags: python, h3

```
import numpy as np
lats = np.random.uniform(0, 90, 1_000_000) 
lons = np.random.uniform(0, 90, 1_000_000)      

import h3
import h3.api.numpy_int
```

Passing numpy arrays straight away:

```
fails with: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

h3.api.numpy_int.geo_to_h3(lats, lons, 6)
```

Following an example from their github issues:

```
fails with: AttributeError: module 'h3' has no attribute 'geo_to_h3_vect'

np.asarray(h3.geo_to_h3_vect(lats, lons, 10))
```

The version of h3 is: 3.7.6

Answer (score 1):

It looks like:

```
from h3.unstable import vect
```

is needed for this.
https://gist.github.com/ajfriend/3eccf3ec01b33f46dc14f5dbb13d8c6f